# Why cannot I subclass UISearchController or UISearchBar

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

Here is my problem,

I have a custom `UIView` and added the `searchController`'s searchbar inside that view, but I am having problems (unwanted UI behavior) with the `searchController`'s searchbar in that view, so I created a seperate searchBar, but it does not search. (But does not give me UI problems.)

In the documentation, I saw that the correct way to do this is subclassing `UISearchController`. Here is the biggest problem, I have no subclassing option for those two. Why would this happen? I already tried cleaning the project, restarting, etc.

[image: No Subclass Option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug in Xcode. Nonetheless, you can create a subclass from these classes **manually**. Just create an empty Swift file and enter the following:

```
import UIKit    

class CustomSearchController: UISearchController {

}
```

or

```
import UIKit    

class CustomSearchBar: UISearchBar {

}
```

Comment: If I start a new project, they are there.. But cannot use them with my ongoing project. I will try this. Thanks

Comment: In iOS 14 it works, in previous version it doesn't